# How to enclose a string within single quotes using a formula in excel?

Tags: excel

For example, I have a string in cell A1 i.e Good
I want the result in cell A2 as "Joseph is a 'Good' boy."

Comment: to put it simply, I wanna know how single and double quotes are handled around strings/numbers/dates/texts using formulas in an excel

Comment: You should edit your question instead of commenting it.

Comment: As simple as this `=CONCAT("""Joseph is a '",A1,"' boy.""")` note `Numbers/Dates` should not be within quotes, only strings are included within quotes. Excel uses double quotations to identify texts/strings within formulas. When it sees these quotes, it uses the text and discards the quotes. Typing quotations directly into a cell is not an issue because Excel automatically recognizes that you are entering text and therefore keeps the quotation marks.

Answer (score 1):

`="Joseph is a '" & A1 & "' boy."` --> Joseph is a 'Good' boy.

`="Josepf is a """ & A1 & """ boy."` --> Joseph is a "Good" boy.